# Windows Phone 7 - Use Native DLL - Need GUID of Class and Interface

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-7, interop, uuid

I need to use C++ Native DLL in Windows Phone 7 application. I am using [DllImport](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1006331) project which shows the way to include native code in Windows Phone 7 Application. It uses FileSystem.dll file to perform actios using Native Code. I need to use my Encryption dll instead of that. The code given uses following way to import functions from FileSystem.dll:

```
[ComImport, Guid("F0D5AFD8-DA24-4e85-9335-BEBCADE5B92A"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class FileSystemClass { }

[ComImport, Guid("2C49FA3D-C6B7-4168-BE80-D044A9C0D9DD"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public partial interface IFileSystemIO { ... }
```

**Only problem is that, I am not able to get the Guid used in ComImport attribute. Anyone knows, how to get the Guid for Class and Interface from Native C++ code?**

Comment: Can you actually use a native/COM DLL in a WP7 app now?!

Comment: Removed the [tag:com-interop] for [tag:windows-phone-7]. Prioritise the communities over the functionalities. This should bring more expert audience to your question. (And [tag:interop] includes the removed one).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to lookup the GUID from your C++ library with an editor or hex viewer, it should be somewhere at the top. See [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16133239&postcount=617) link.